# Return a partial view from a razor page Handler

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am having a problem returning a partial view from a razor page, my scenario is

I have a partial view which is a form and that has a model. I have 3 forms residing on a single razor pages
Form A post a ModelA
Form B post ModelB
My problem is, i want to handle thier specific post event on the parent Page which is a razor page. 
How would i return this partial view

```
OnPostModelA(ModelA model) 
{
   if(! ModelState.IsValid)
        return Partialview("_CreateModelA", model);

}
```

Is this possible using razor pages or this is not possible? 
I just want to return the partialview with its designated model using ajax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. As you know ,Razor Pages have no equivalent `PartialView` method on the `PageModel`. If you do want to invoke different parial views in `PageModel` method , simply add a `PartialView` Helper Method in you `PageModel`:

   ```
   [NonAction]
   public virtual PartialViewResult PartialView(string viewName, object model)
   {
       ViewData.Model = model;

       return new PartialViewResult()
       {
           ViewName = viewName,
           ViewData = ViewData,
           TempData = TempData
       };
   }
   ```

Here I use a `ViewData.Model` to store your model object , let's say your Model type is named as `X1Model` :

you can use it across the partial views .

Create a simple partial view named as `_CreateModelA.cshtml`  :

```
@model HelloModel

AAAAA
<div>
    @Model.Model.Welcome
</div>
```

and another partial view named as `_CreateModelB.cshtml` :

```
@model HelloModel

BBBBBBBB
<div>
    @Model.Model.Welcome
</div>
```

At last , you can return `PartialView` in your PageModel:

```
public class HelloModel : PageModel
{

    public X1Model Model { get; set; }

    public ActionResult OnGet(int rand = 0)
    {
        var flag = rand % 2 == 0 ? true : false;
        var model = new HelloModel() {
            Model = new X1Model {
                Welcome = "Hello,world",
            }
        }; 
        if (flag)
        {
            return PartialView("_CreateModelA", model);
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_CreateModelB", model);
        }
    }

    [NonAction]
    public virtual PartialViewResult PartialView(string viewName, object model)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot :

[image]

2. However , it is not recommended to put partial view logic in PageModel . Using it in the Page file as below is much nicer:

```js
@if(){
    <partial name="" />
}else{
    <partial name="" /> 
}
```

Comment: I know that there is no partial returns in razor pages. Im thinking of this work around but I don't know how to bind the model the way you did.

Comment: I do not know how to bind the model the way you did. Would definitely give this a try

Comment: @EduCielo , the PageModel has a Model property to store model that will be used in your partial view .When invoking the partial view by `PartialView(viewname , pagemodel)` , we will pass the `PageModel` to the partial view . As a result , you can retrieve the model by `YourPageModel.Model.xx`  in a strongly-typed way.

Comment: Got it. That was a good workaround. Im looking at this kind of scenario in the razor documentation since it is very possible to happen but to no avail. Thanks mate

Comment: @EduCielo , I'm glad to hear that it helps . If you find my workaround works , could you please mark my reply as an answer . It will also help others guys who have the same doubts to find the answer quickly.  Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

In [asp dotnet core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2), Microsoft added a Partial method to the PageModel class that works similar to the PartialView method on the Controller class. It however doesn't allow you to pass ViewData to the view. So, if you need to do that, then you can create your own PartialViewResult like so:

```cs
var resultViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<YourModelType>(ViewData, model);
resultViewData[YourViewDataProperty] = yourViewDataValue;
return new PartialViewResult
{
    ViewName = "_Branch",
    ViewData = resultViewData,
    TempData = TempData
};
```